# readymade miniforum for my website?

Tags: forum

hey guys,
i'm looking for a finished product that i can use on my website. just a really simpel forum, where people can register and then post questions or discuss something. i wouldn't even need topics or subforums. just one category would be enough.

i know there is stuff out there like phpbb forums, however most of that is too advanced for my needs.

regards and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try http://www.ninjapost.com since it meets your needs of (1) simplicity and (2) ready made.

Answer (score 0):

While phpbb is complex, it can be used for your purposes.

[Wikipedia has a great list of forum software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Internet_forum_software). Let me know if none of these work, and I will dig up my research on various forum systems.

Erick